# Schema Validation Failing during Helm upgrade

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a service which does Helm upgrade in the background with the values we provide.
But the upgrade is failing with the following error :
`Error: values don't meet the specifications of the schema(s) in the following chart(s):\nairflow:\n- scheduler: Additional property persistence is not allowed`

My values.yaml does not have a persistence set in the scheduler section. I tried to validate the values against the values_json schema but no luck